# Client sends "FIN, ACK" instead of "Client Hello" | Connection closed during SSL handshake | Haproxy

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, haproxy, node.js, .net

I am trying to establish SSL connection between the .NET WebSocket Client and my server by calling "wss://domain.xyz". Haproxy is handling the SSL handshake and once that is done it connect to a NodeJs server running on the same server.
Currently, I am facing an issue where after TCP handshake is made, client sends ACK and FIN, ACK packets instead of "Client Hello" to server. And getting below error in haproxy log.

***secured/1: Connection closed during SSL handshake***

Normally, that would indicate that this is a client code issue. The confusing part is that the client is able to do ssl handshake when calling "wss://echo.websocket.org".
But also the Haproxy configuration looks like its working fine since I am able to do ssl handshake using browser (Chrome, IE11, Edge, Firefox) and "WebSocket Test Client" chrome add-on. Ssllabs confirms that part as well. Client is also able to open non-secure websocket connection.

**Haproxy -vv**

```
HA-Proxy version 2.0.18-1ppa1~bionic 2020/09/30 - https://haproxy.org/
Build options :
  TARGET  = linux-glibc
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/haproxy-VtLTwE/haproxy-2.0.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-old-style-declaration -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference
  OPTIONS = USE_PCRE2=1 USE_PCRE2_JIT=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1

Feature list : +EPOLL -KQUEUE -MY_EPOLL -MY_SPLICE +NETFILTER -PCRE -PCRE_JIT +PCRE2 +PCRE2_JIT +POLL -PRIVATE_CACHE +THREAD -PTHREAD_PSHARED +REGPARM -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +TPROXY +LINUX_TPROXY +LINUX_SPLICE +LIBCRYPT +CRYPT_H -VSYSCALL +GETADDRINFO +OPENSSL +LUA +FUTEX +ACCEPT4 -MY_ACCEPT4 +ZLIB -SLZ +CPU_AFFINITY +TFO +NS +DL +RT -DEVICEATLAS -51DEGREES -WURFL +SYSTEMD -OBSOLETE_LINKER +PRCTL +THREAD_DUMP -EVPORTS

Default settings :
  bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with multi-threading support (MAX_THREADS=64, default=1).
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.3
Built with network namespace support.
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Built with zlib version : 1.2.11
Running on zlib version : 1.2.11
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with PCRE2 version : 10.31 2018-02-12
PCRE2 library supports JIT : yes
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with the Prometheus exporter as a service

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available multiplexer protocols :
(protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
              h2 : mode=HTX        side=FE|BE     mux=H2
              h2 : mode=HTTP       side=FE        mux=H2
       <default> : mode=HTX        side=FE|BE     mux=H1
       <default> : mode=TCP|HTTP   side=FE|BE     mux=PASS

Available services :
        prometheus-exporter

Available filters :
        [SPOE] spoe
        [COMP] compression
        [CACHE] cache
        [TRACE] trace
```

Below is my HaProxy configuration. I am suspecting I am doing something wrong in it.

**Haproxy configuration**

```
global
  log /dev/log local0
  maxconn 4096
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  ca-base /etc/haproxy/certs
  crt-base /etc/haproxy/certs
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  tune.ssl.cachesize 100000
  tune.ssl.lifetime 6000
  #ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
  ssl-default-server-options force-tlsv12
  ssl-default-bind-options force-tlsv12 no-tls-tickets
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:DES-CBC3-SHA:RSA+3DES
  ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:DES-CBC3-SHA:RSA+3DES 

defaults
  mode http
  log global
  maxconn 4096
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  retries 3      
  timeout connect 30s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s
  # Long timeout for WebSocket connections.
  timeout tunnel 1h
  timeout http-keep-alive 10s
  timeout check 10s

frontend secured
  bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domain.com.pem alpn http/1.1 ca-file /etc/haproxy/certs/domain.com.ca
  #reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
  http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors domain.com"
  http-request add-header X-Custom-SSL-Cipher %sslc
  http-request add-header X-Custom-SSL-Version %sslv
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  use_backend node if is_websocket
  mode http
  default_backend node 

#frontend unsecured
  mode http
  bind *:80
  acl http      ssl_fc,not
  http-request redirect scheme https if http

  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
  http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors domain.com"
  bind *:443 ssl crt hostname.com.pem alpn http/1.1

  acl is_websocket hdr_end(host) -i WebSocket
  use_backend node if is_websocket
  default_backend node

backend node
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  timeout check 50000ms
  http-request set-header Host domain.com
  server node1 127.0.0.1:8080 check inter 500ms
```

**Wireshark pcap**

```
34  2.285439    192.168.10.19   178.XX.XX.XXX   TCP 66  55514 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
37  2.373956    178.XX.XX.XXX   192.168.10.19   TCP 66  443 → 55514 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
38  2.374042    192.168.10.19   178.XX.XX.XXX   TCP 54  55514 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=132096 Len=0
39  2.406464    192.168.10.19   178.XX.XX.XXX   TCP 54  55514 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=132096 Len=0
45  2.495315    178.XX.XX.XXX   192.168.10.19   TCP 60  443 → 55514 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=64256 Len=0
46  2.495364    192.168.10.19   178.XX.XX.XXX   TCP 54  55514 → 443 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=2 Win=132096 Len=0
```

**openssl s_client -connect domain.zyx:443**

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:/etc/haproxy# openssl s_client -connect domain.xyz:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = domain.xyz
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = domain.xyz
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Certificate)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = domain.xyz

issuer=C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4951 bytes and written 409 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
    Session-ID: ***************************************************************E
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: *************************************************************************************2
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1601745936
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out
content-length: 110
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: text/html
connection: close

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
closed
```

I tried using all tls versions, verified cipher suites even though it didn't get to that point. In addition, I checked all client debugs but there were no errors. I wonder if calling wss:// uri from .net application needs to be handled differently in haproxy or If I need to configure anything on Domain website provider or hosting provider website. Machine is running Ubuntu 18.04 and client is running on .NET 2.0 (also tried with .NET3.5 & .NET 4.x). I am confused to which end is having the issue here since both work fine but not working together.

Would really appreciate it if you could help me debug this. If I missed any information please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the developer console in your browser.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton thanks for your reply. Currently Developer console will show "GET https://domain.xyz/ 404 (Not Found) but this is expected since I only have a websocket running atm. I can see in Wireshark the handshake is being done correctly, Its only when I call it from the .NET application I am getting the "connection closed during SSL handshake" message. But .NET application can do the ssl handshake with other websites when using the wss uri.

Comment: There is no SSL even involved in the failed connection you show. This means that any changes to ciphers, certificates etc will not matter at all. There are no application data at all exchanged, so the problem cannot be at the WSS or HTTP level either. This looks for me solely like a problem of the client (nothing useful known about this) or of the connection between client and server (i.e. maybe firewalls or similar involved).